# Expand All and Collapse All functionality on Button Click

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

[image]I am using the PnP SPFx Accordion control in my SPFx solution I want make all Accordion Expanded and Collapsible on button Click.

Below is my one accordion I am changing the state on button click but some how it does not work.

```
<Accordion title="Overview" defaultCollapsed={this.state.overviewAccordionCollapsed} className={styles.itemCell} > <div className={styles.itemContent}> <div className={styles.itemReponse}> </div> </div> </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to post your issue to their github Issues page.

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultCollapsed` property is a property that controls the component default expanded state, it is not the state property that controls whether the component is expanded.
[image]
Through the react development tool, we can find that the property that controls the extended state of the component is controlled by expanded in the component state, but the component does not expose the method to control this property to us.
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to update the expanded state property from the parent component

Comment: The component does not provide such a method.